# C# problem automatically converting tab char to space

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm experiencing a problem where tab char seems to be automatically converted to a space randomly.

```
char Delimiter = '\t'; // \t is tab
string headers = $"Column1{Delimiter}Column2{Delimiter}Column3{Delimiter}Column4{Delimiter}Column5{Delimiter}Column6{Delimiter}Column7";
string outputFilePathAndName = "C:/MyOutputFile";
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilePathAndName, append: true);
writer.WriteLine(headers);
writer.Flush();
```

Expected output:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5    Column6    Column7
```

Actual output:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3    Column4    Column5    Column6    Column7
```

**Any idea why the first 2 tabs always come out as spaces instead of tabs?**

Things I have tried:

- Using string concatenation instead of interpolation
- Pasting in a tab character instead of '\t'
- Opening the output file with different text editors
- Examining the string `headers` while debugging, it looks correct.
- Hard-coding the line as `Column1\tColumn2\tColumn3\t...`

Is this a bug with StreamWriter?

Comment: What version of .NET?

Comment: Output looks correct to me trying your code.

Comment: @VictorWilson using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: And you are looking at the correct outputfile? And not something previously generated? And you looking at it with an editor without magic? Where you can actually see that the character is a tab or not?

Comment: @Ralf yes, I deleted the file and regenerated it multiple times. I used Notepad and Notepad++ to view it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  I get the correct output.

Comment: And you used the same column names as in the example ? Or at least column names with equal length? If you only see the problem with different length columnnames  you might need to rethink what tabs do.

Comment: How do you know they're spaces? I've had people accuse a tab of being a space when the column length were such that the tab only moved along by the width of one space. It's still a tab, even if the column is 7 chars long and the tab stop is 8. If you're looking in some text editor, set your tab stop size to 100 to see them expand. If you're looking a hex editor, check for 0x09 (tab) between strings. Space is 0x20. Download this: https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/ , use it to open the file, put a screenshot of the whole hex editor window into your question

Comment: Please show content of the resulting file as HEX bytes so we can see where `x20` are in the string.

Comment: Amuses me that your "expected output" here has spaces ;)

Comment: If you don't have a hex editor at hand. Notepad++ which you seem to have has a "show all Characters" button that will show you characters normally "hidden". A Tab will look like an arrow.

Comment: Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzviD.png - post something like this into your question so we can see

Comment: Thanks for all the comments/questions everyone. After using the Notepad++ feature "show whitespace and tab" I found that actually it was outputting tabs that sometimes appear visually as a single space, depending on what the text is (rather annoying but it is what it is). If someone wants to post that as an answer I can mark it as the solution then close this question, but I will leave it up rather than delete it because I think many others will have the same question and these comments can help others to understand the visually deceptive output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could have sworn I was seeing spaces, but this was actually a visual glitch where tab characters appeared visually as just spaces, even in basic text editors like Notepad. I don't know the reason why they appear as different lengths, but the best way I found to tell for sure what characters are present is to **use Notepad++ and select the option View >Show symbol >Show white space and tab**. When you do that it will show tabs like an arrow and spaces as a dot.

[image: visual of tab characters that look different]

Normally I would delete a post like this since there was actually no bug, it was a mistake on my part, but I will leave it up with my answer here because, as evidenced by [Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard)'s comment, other people have had the same question and I'm sure more people will have the same question in the future.

Credit to those who helped me understand this with their comments. I'm just posting this answer on their behalf since no one posted an official answer.

Comment: A TAB is not "8 spaces", but "move the next position to a multiple of 8" (but that 8 may also be configured to be 4 or other) . Type in "a TAB b" (no spaces) in Notepad, then add extra chars to that "a" - the "b" starts at a multiple of 8 positions, and usually doesn't move